# How to solve error on Ruby Gems install Hiptest-publisher?

Tags: ubuntu, ruby, gem

I am working to setup a Configuration around Robot-Testing Framework on Ubuntu 18.04 - 64bit architecture. In order to run some tests onto my server I need to run the following application.

hiptest-publisher with config file as follow

```
token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
language = robotframework
output_directory = './'
site = https://app.hiptest.com
with_folders = true
```

Hiptest-publisher is a ruby base library - I have installed Ruby no problem - but when I tried to run - the installed `$ sudo gem install hiptest-publisher`

I got the following error;

```
Fetching: colorize-0.8.1.gem (100%)
Successfully installed colorize-0.8.1
Fetching: parseconfig-1.0.8.gem (100%)
Successfully installed parseconfig-1.0.8
Fetching: concurrent-ruby-1.1.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed concurrent-ruby-1.1.5
Fetching: i18n-0.9.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed i18n-0.9.5
Fetching: mini_portile2-2.4.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed mini_portile2-2.4.0
Fetching: nokogiri-1.9.1.gem (100%)
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing hiptest-publisher:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.9.1/ext/nokogiri
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20190911-10379-wiu657.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.4.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... no
zlib is missing; necessary for building libxml2
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.5
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.9.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/nokogiri-1.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.5.0/nokogiri-1.9.1/gem_make.out
```

Also tried to update the gems like; `sudo gem update --system`

-- It error again with;

```
* Process memory map:

5607ad381000-5607ad382000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7615542                    /usr/bin/ruby2.5
5607ad581000-5607ad582000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 7615542                    /usr/bin/ruby2.5
5607ad582000-5607ad583000 rw-p 00001000 fd:00 7615542                    /usr/bin/ruby2.5
5607ad8ba000-5607b6cc3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [heap]
7f297c000000-7f297c021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f297c021000-7f2980000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f298054d000-7f29815fa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f298206a000-7f298225a000 r--s 00000000 fd:00 10490835                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f298225a000-7f298285b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f29828e4000-7f2982b86000 r--s 00000000 fd:00 7616056                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.5.so.2.5.1
7f2982b86000-7f2982b9d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2982b9d000-7f2982d9c000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 10490872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2982d9c000-7f2982d9d000 r--p 00016000 fd:00 10490872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2982d9d000-7f2982d9e000 rw-p 00017000 fd:00 10490872                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f2982d9e000-7f2982db5000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490974                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
7f2982db5000-7f2982fb5000 ---p 00017000 fd:00 10490974                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
7f2982fb5000-7f2982fb6000 r--p 00017000 fd:00 10490974                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
7f2982fb6000-7f2982fb7000 rw-p 00018000 fd:00 10490974                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.27.so
7f2982fb7000-7f2982fb9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2982fb9000-7f2982fbe000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490923                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
7f2982fbe000-7f29831be000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 10490923                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
7f29831be000-7f29831bf000 r--p 00005000 fd:00 10490923                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
7f29831bf000-7f29831c0000 rw-p 00006000 fd:00 10490923                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns-2.27.so
7f29831c0000-7f29831c2000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490931                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f29831c2000-7f29833c1000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 10490931                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f29833c1000-7f29833c2000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 10490931                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f29833c2000-7f29833c3000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 10490931                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2
7f29833c3000-7f29833ce000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f29833ce000-7f29835cd000 ---p 0000b000 fd:00 10490925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f29835cd000-7f29835ce000 r--p 0000a000 fd:00 10490925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f29835ce000-7f29835cf000 rw-p 0000b000 fd:00 10490925                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.27.so
7f29835cf000-7f29835d5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f29835d5000-7f29835d6000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f29835d6000-7f29837d7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f29837d7000-7f29837da000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870716                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/cgi/escape.so
7f29837da000-7f29839d9000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 7870716                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/cgi/escape.so
7f29839d9000-7f29839da000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 7870716                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/cgi/escape.so
7f29839da000-7f29839db000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 7870716                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/cgi/escape.so
7f29839db000-7f2983a09000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 5509446                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/date-2.0.0/lib/date_core.so
7f2983a09000-7f2983c09000 ---p 0002e000 fd:00 5509446                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/date-2.0.0/lib/date_core.so
7f2983c09000-7f2983c0a000 r--p 0002e000 fd:00 5509446                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/date-2.0.0/lib/date_core.so
7f2983c0a000-7f2983c0b000 rw-p 0002f000 fd:00 5509446                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/date-2.0.0/lib/date_core.so
7f2983c0b000-7f2983c0c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2983c0c000-7f2983c0e000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/windows_31j.so
7f2983c0e000-7f2983e0e000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 7870788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/windows_31j.so
7f2983e0e000-7f2983e0f000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 7870788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/windows_31j.so
7f2983e0f000-7f2983e10000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 7870788                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/windows_31j.so
7f2983e10000-7f2983e2c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10491007                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f2983e2c000-7f298402b000 ---p 0001c000 fd:00 10491007                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f298402b000-7f298402c000 r--p 0001b000 fd:00 10491007                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f298402c000-7f298402d000 rw-p 0001c000 fd:00 10491007                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.11
7f298402d000-7f298403b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/zlib.so
7f298403b000-7f298423b000 ---p 0000e000 fd:00 7870816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/zlib.so
7f298423b000-7f298423c000 r--p 0000e000 fd:00 7870816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/zlib.so
7f298423c000-7f298423d000 rw-p 0000f000 fd:00 7870816                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/zlib.so
7f298423d000-7f298423f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870797                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/wait.so
7f298423f000-7f298443e000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 7870797                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/wait.so
7f298443e000-7f298443f000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 7870797                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/wait.so
7f298443f000-7f2984440000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 7870797                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/wait.so
7f2984440000-7f298446a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870812                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/socket.so
7f298446a000-7f2984669000 ---p 0002a000 fd:00 7870812                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/socket.so
7f2984669000-7f298466a000 r--p 00029000 fd:00 7870812                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/socket.so
7f298466a000-7f298466b000 rw-p 0002a000 fd:00 7870812                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/socket.so
7f298466b000-7f298466c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/nonblock.so
7f298466c000-7f298486c000 ---p 00001000 fd:00 7870796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/nonblock.so
7f298486c000-7f298486d000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 7870796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/nonblock.so
7f298486d000-7f298486e000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 7870796                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/io/nonblock.so
7f298486e000-7f2984871000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870727                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/digest.so
7f2984871000-7f2984a70000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 7870727                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/digest.so
7f2984a70000-7f2984a71000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 7870727                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/digest.so
7f2984a71000-7f2984a72000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 7870727                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/digest.so
7f2984a72000-7f2984d0d000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7610269                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
7f2984d0d000-7f2984f0c000 ---p 0029b000 fd:00 7610269                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
7f2984f0c000-7f2984f38000 r--p 0029a000 fd:00 7610269                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
7f2984f38000-7f2984f3a000 rw-p 002c6000 fd:00 7610269                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1
7f2984f3a000-7f2984f3d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2984f3d000-7f2984fbd000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7611071                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
7f2984fbd000-7f29851bd000 ---p 00080000 fd:00 7611071                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
7f29851bd000-7f29851c6000 r--p 00080000 fd:00 7611071                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
7f29851c6000-7f29851ca000 rw-p 00089000 fd:00 7611071                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1
7f29851ca000-7f298521c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870804                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/openssl.so
7f298521c000-7f298541c000 ---p 00052000 fd:00 7870804                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/openssl.so
7f298541c000-7f298541f000 r--p 00052000 fd:00 7870804                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/openssl.so
7f298541f000-7f2985420000 rw-p 00055000 fd:00 7870804                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/openssl.so
7f2985420000-7f2985425000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/strscan.so
7f2985425000-7f2985624000 ---p 00005000 fd:00 7870814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/strscan.so
7f2985624000-7f2985625000 r--p 00004000 fd:00 7870814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/strscan.so
7f2985625000-7f2985626000 rw-p 00005000 fd:00 7870814                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/strscan.so
7f2985626000-7f2985647000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 5512123                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.so
7f2985647000-7f2985847000 ---p 00021000 fd:00 5512123                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.so
7f2985847000-7f2985848000 r--p 00021000 fd:00 5512123                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.so
7f2985848000-7f2985849000 rw-p 00022000 fd:00 5512123                    /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/psych-3.1.0/lib/psych.so
7f2985849000-7f298584f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870789                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/etc.so
7f298584f000-7f2985a4e000 ---p 00006000 fd:00 7870789                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/etc.so
7f2985a4e000-7f2985a4f000 r--p 00005000 fd:00 7870789                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/etc.so
7f2985a4f000-7f2985a50000 rw-p 00006000 fd:00 7870789                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/etc.so
7f2985a50000-7f2985a57000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870813                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/stringio.so
7f2985a57000-7f2985c57000 ---p 00007000 fd:00 7870813                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/stringio.so
7f2985c57000-7f2985c58000 r--p 00007000 fd:00 7870813                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/stringio.so
7f2985c58000-7f2985c59000 rw-p 00008000 fd:00 7870813                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/stringio.so
7f2985c59000-7f2985c5b000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870775                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/trans/transdb.so
7f2985c5b000-7f2985e5b000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 7870775                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/trans/transdb.so
7f2985e5b000-7f2985e5c000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 7870775                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/trans/transdb.so
7f2985e5c000-7f2985e5d000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 7870775                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/trans/transdb.so
7f2985e5d000-7f2985e5f000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7870732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/encdb.so
7f2985e5f000-7f298605e000 ---p 00002000 fd:00 7870732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/encdb.so
7f298605e000-7f298605f000 r--p 00001000 fd:00 7870732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/encdb.so
7f298605f000-7f2986060000 rw-p 00002000 fd:00 7870732                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ruby/2.5.0/enc/encdb.so
7f2986060000-7f2986a2f000 r--p 00000000 fd:00 7608939                    /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
7f2986a2f000-7f2986bcc000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490898                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f2986bcc000-7f2986dcb000 ---p 0019d000 fd:00 10490898                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f2986dcb000-7f2986dcc000 r--p 0019c000 fd:00 10490898                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f2986dcc000-7f2986dcd000 rw-p 0019d000 fd:00 10490898                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
7f2986dcd000-7f2986dd6000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490845                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
7f2986dd6000-7f2986fd5000 ---p 00009000 fd:00 10490845                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
7f2986fd5000-7f2986fd6000 r--p 00008000 fd:00 10490845                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
7f2986fd6000-7f2986fd7000 rw-p 00009000 fd:00 10490845                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.27.so
7f2986fd7000-7f2987005000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2987005000-7f2987008000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490858                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f2987008000-7f2987207000 ---p 00003000 fd:00 10490858                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f2987207000-7f2987208000 r--p 00002000 fd:00 10490858                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f2987208000-7f2987209000 rw-p 00003000 fd:00 10490858                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.27.so
7f2987209000-7f2987288000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7610497                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f2987288000-7f2987488000 ---p 0007f000 fd:00 7610497                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f2987488000-7f2987489000 r--p 0007f000 fd:00 7610497                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f2987489000-7f298748a000 rw-p 00080000 fd:00 7610497                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmp.so.10.3.2
7f298748a000-7f29874a4000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490968                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f29874a4000-7f29876a3000 ---p 0001a000 fd:00 10490968                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f29876a3000-7f29876a4000 r--p 00019000 fd:00 10490968                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f29876a4000-7f29876a5000 rw-p 0001a000 fd:00 10490968                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
7f29876a5000-7f29876a9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f29876a9000-7f2987890000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490835                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f2987890000-7f2987a90000 ---p 001e7000 fd:00 10490835                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f2987a90000-7f2987a94000 r--p 001e7000 fd:00 10490835                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f2987a94000-7f2987a96000 rw-p 001eb000 fd:00 10490835                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
7f2987a96000-7f2987a9a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2987a9a000-7f2987d35000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 7616056                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.5.so.2.5.1
7f2987d35000-7f2987f34000 ---p 0029b000 fd:00 7616056                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.5.so.2.5.1
7f2987f34000-7f2987f3a000 r--p 0029a000 fd:00 7616056                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.5.so.2.5.1
7f2987f3a000-7f2987f3b000 rw-p 002a0000 fd:00 7616056                    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libruby-2.5.so.2.5.1
7f2987f3b000-7f2987f4b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2987f4b000-7f2987f72000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 10490807                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f2987ff5000-7f298815e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f298816b000-7f298816d000 r--s 00000000 fd:00 7615542                    /usr/bin/ruby2.5
7f298816d000-7f298816e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f298816e000-7f2988172000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f2988172000-7f2988173000 r--p 00027000 fd:00 10490807                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f2988173000-7f2988174000 rw-p 00028000 fd:00 10490807                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.27.so
7f2988174000-7f2988175000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7ffd3e6d2000-7ffd3eed1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffd3ef49000-7ffd3ef4c000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffd3ef4c000-7ffd3ef4d000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted
```

Is there anyone which know to solve this ... 
Thanks..

Comment: Update -- I have found a way to resolve the problem - by `intel-nuc@intel-nuc:~/Developer/pivi-parking/ci/stages/robot_tests/hiptest$ sudo apt install build-essential patch ruby-dev zlib1g-dev liblzma-dev -y` - I managed to all missing dependencies spacially the Zlib one

Comment: And we that I am now able to install the *Hiptest-publisher* gem lib -- `Fetching: hiptest-publisher-1.28.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed hiptest-publisher-1.28.0`

Comment: Check all logs here [link](https://pastebin.com/wBScjuxN)